# os function to both join directories and create them?

Tags: python, operating-system, directory, mkdir, mkdirs

Currently if I want to specify and create a new directory, I'll do:

```
newPath = os.path.join(oldPath,"newfolder")
if(not os.path.exists(newPath)): os.makedirs(newPath)
```

I'm wondering if a pre-packaged `os` function (or in other package) exists to do this in one function? I know I can make my own but I'd rather a pre-packaged solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try [pylib](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pylib/)'s `path` functionality.

It's basically a really nice OOP (*Object Oriented*) abstraction around local paths (*and svn paths*).

**Example:**

```
from py.path import local

p = local("/some/path").join("/some/other/path").mkdir("/some/oth/path")
```

*NB:* The above example is contrived. Please refer to the documentation.